# OAuth2 callback: redirect after getting an access token by authenticating a code

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, claims-based-identity, google-api-php-client

Taking a look at this [google client api for php example](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/a88dcec6833ac2de4798c13a24abe30c90feb057/examples/idtoken.php)

I noticed this part of the code:

```
/************************************************
  If we have a code back from the OAuth 2.0 flow,
  we need to exchange that with the authenticate()
  function. We store the resultant access token
  bundle in the session, and redirect to ourself.
 ************************************************/
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

The thing is I don't get the redirect (`header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));`). In fact you can remove it and everything seems to go on just fine. So, why is it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which redirect you don't get?

The code-for-token-exchange is part of the standard Oauth2 flow (the so called "Authorization Grant"). You can read about the exchange here: https://docs.auth0.com/protocols#4 (or in the spec here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31#section-4.1). The spec is a little bit harder to parse.

The `code` is posted to a specific location on your website (`/callback`), because it is usually a fixed location registered with the IdP. Any other redirects after that, are often to send the user to the actual resource they wanted to land on originally. Or simply to the (authenticated) home. For example: this might happen if the user wants to go to `https://yoursite/someplace` but they need to be authenticated: the entire flow happens, and afterwards they are redirected to `/someplace`.